# how to use split in angular5 for wordcount

Tags: angular

I am trying to do the wordcount in textarea but it shows after page load Words:1. whats wrong in this and what i need to do. can anyone please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

My `component.html`

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="review.Roman" name="Roman" id='text' required></textarea>
<p>Words:{{value.length}}</p>
```

My `component.ts`

```
export class PostReviewComponent implements OnInit {
    value: any = {};
    reviews: Reviews[];
    review: Reviews = {
        Roman:''
    };

    ngOnInit() {
        var str = this.review.Roman;
        this.value = str.split(' ');
    }
}
```

I have few more values in my Reviews array here i am showing only Roman.

Comment: Your property `value` should be an `Array` type instead of an `object`. `.length` will return `undefined` on objects.

Comment: Not working now I gave array -->value:any={};let re = /\s/g;
var str=this.review.Roman;
this.value=str.split(re);

Comment: sorry value:any=[];

Comment: see my answer below and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
let re = /\s/g

this.value=str.split(re)
```

You just need to use RE instead for hardcoded space

Let me know if there is any issue

Comment: Not working. I wrote like this---->
let re = /\s/g
var str=this.review.Roman
this.value=str.split(re)

Comment: can you please check the value of  str ?

Comment: I checked in console.log(this.value.length); It shows Words:1

Comment: I mean please check the value of 'str' whether it is empty of something else

Answer (score 0):

The reason it shows after page load is because of the code you have in your `ngOnInit` method that gets executed when the page loads.

Best way is to use [angular pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) and using this way you can re-utilize anywhere in your code. Having something like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'wordsCount'})
export class WordsCountPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): number {
    return value.split(' ').length;
  }
}
```

And then in your `component.html`

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="review.Roman" name="Roman" id='text' required></textarea>
<p>Words:{{value | wordsCount}}</p>
```

**Note**: Remember to register custom pipes in the declaration array.

**EDIT**:
If you don't want to use pipes you can use `(ngModelChange)` to update your `value` property.

In your `component.html`

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="review.Roman" (ngModelChange)="valueChanges($event)"></textarea><br>
{{value.length}}
```

and then in your `component.ts` add `valueChanges` method:

```
export class PostReviewComponent implements OnInit {
    value: any = [];
    reviews: Reviews[];
    review: Reviews = {
        Roman:''
    };

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    valueChanges(modelValue: string) {
        this.value = modelValue.split(' ');  
    }
}
```

Every time your model is updated, it will update the word count.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not a problem. Don’t forget to accept this answer so others can see :)